# How to extract characteristics from text using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, machine-learning-model

I would like to develop some kind of model/algorithm that allows me to *extract the characteristics of a given product name*. (let's say the brand, model and color).

I am looking for a solution similar to the one offered by *MonkeyLearn* and its model *Laptop Feature Extract*.

For example:

Given the item "Apple iPhone 6s, 64GB Silver", It should compute:

```
{
  brand: "iPhone",
  model: "6s",
  capacity: "64Gb",
  color: "Silver"
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: generally similar problem i was saw as parsing agent ...just for example i am saying..can u check the below one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281114/how-to-parse-user-agent-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to look for is called "Named Entity recognition". From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition)

> Named-entity recognition (NER) (also known as entity identification,
>   entity chunking and entity extraction) is a subtask of information
>   extraction that seeks to locate and classify named entity mentions in
>   unstructured text into pre-defined categories such as the person
>   names, organizations, locations, medical codes, time expressions,
>   quantities, monetary values, percentages, etc.

There are already trained models for that, but most of them are for generic usage. For example in Python

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp('European authorities fined Google a record $5.1 billion on Wednesday for abusing its power in the mobile phone market and ordered the company to alter its practices')
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents])
```

The output is

```
[('European', 'NORP'), 
('Google', 'ORG'), 
('$5.1 billion', 'MONEY'), 
('Wednesday', 'DATE')]
```

Source of code: [TowardsDataScience](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da)

In your case, you have to either train an NER yourself for phone specifications or find one that is available in public.